# How to computed and add a new column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, multiplication, calculated-columns

I have two tables

[Table_1] - Amount of money in a specific currency.

```
Currency  | Amount  
USD       |  243  
USD       |  212  
USD       |  432   
EUR       |  578  
EUR       |  112  
EUR       |  578  
GBP       |  965  
GBP       |  309
```

And [Table_2] - Exchange rate EUR and GBP to USD

```
Cur |   FX  
GBP | 1.43  
EUR | 1.18  
USD | 1
```

I need to permanently add a new column [Amount in USD] into [Table_1] which converts all currencies into USD. Basically I need the corresponding currencies to be multiplied by the exchange rates given in [Table_2]. The final result should look like this.

```
Currency  | Amount  |Amount in USD  
USD       |   243   |   243  
USD       |   212   |   212  
USD       |   432   |   432  
EUR       |   578   |   682  
EUR       |   112   |   132  
EUR       |   578   |   682  
GBP       |   965   |   1380  
GBP       |   309   |   442
```

I would appreciate if someone could help out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about, instead of using a computed column, using a `VIEW`?

Comment: Not sure, I have never worked with VIEW. My real database has around 10 mln rows and I will need to use the computed column in further computations. Will that work in VIEW as well?

Comment: Yes, to quote from [MS Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views): *A view is a virtual table whose contents are defined by a query. Like a table, a view consists of a set of named columns and rows of data. Unless indexed, a view does not exist as a stored set of data values in a database. The rows and columns of data come from tables referenced in the query defining the view and are produced dynamically when the view is referenced.*  So you can query it just like a normal table. Have a look at my solution below for how to create a View, or Computed Column.

Comment: The code worked, but when I check the solutions the view table only shows the computed column. My actual database has 28 columns all of which need to be visible.

Comment: Your sample data only included 3 columns, so that's what you got :). If you need more columns, you'll need to add those to the views DDL. I don't have access to your system, so I don't know you have more columns. If you have questions on a specific solution, however, comment the answer, not your question.

Comment: Alright I will keep it mind next time. The function bit worked though, so I have exactly what I wanted thx for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions for you. One using a `VIEW`, the other a computed column (which is what you stated you wanted) by means of a scalar function:

```
--Create sample data
CREATE TABLE ExchangeRate (Currency char(3), FX decimal(8,2));
INSERT INTO ExchangeRate
VALUES ('GBP',1.43),
       ('EUR',1.18),
       ('USD',1);
GO

CREATE TABLE TransactionList (Currency char(3), Amount decimal(12,2));

INSERT INTO TransactionList
VALUES ('GBP',100),
       ('EUR', 100),
       ('USD',100);
GO
--View Solution
CREATE VIEW ValuesInUSD AS

    SELECT TL.Currency, TL.Amount, TL.Amount * ER.FX AS USDAmount
    FROM TransactionList TL
         JOIN ExchangeRate ER ON TL.Currency = ER.Currency;
GO
--Check results
SELECT *
FROM ValuesInUSD;

GO
--Function Solution
--Create Function
CREATE FUNCTION ExchangeToUSD (@Currency char(3), @Value decimal(12,2))
RETURNS DECIMAL(12,2)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @USD decimal(12,2);

    SELECT @USD =  @Value * FX
    FROM ExchangeRate
    WHERE Currency = @Currency;

    RETURN @USD;

END
GO
--Add Computed Column
ALTER TABLE TransactionList ADD ValueInUSD AS (dbo.ExchangeToUSD(Currency, Amount));
GO
--Check results
SELECT *
FROM TransactionList;
GO
--Clean up
DROP VIEW ValuesInUSD;
DROP TABLE TransactionList;
DROP FUNCTION ExchangeToUSD;
DROP TABLE ExchangeRate;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
SELECT 
    Currency
    ,Amount
    ,CEILING(ROUND((Amount*FX),1)) AS [Amount in USD]
FROM Table_1 c1 
INNER JOIN Table_2 c2
ON c2.Cur=c1.Currency
```

Result

```
Currency    Amount  Amount in USD
-----------------------------------
USD          243       243
USD          212       212
USD          432       432
EUR          578       682
EUR          112       133
EUR          578       682
GBP          965       1380
GBP          309       442
```

Comment: The OP stated they want a computed column on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
CREATE  TABLE #Currency (Currency NVARCHAR(10),AMOUNT INT)
CREATE TABLE #Exchange_Rate (Currency NVARCHAR(10),FX DECIMAL(15,2))

INSERT INTO #Exchange_Rate
SELECT 'GBP', 1.43    UNION ALL
SELECT 'EUR', 1.18     UNION ALL
SELECT 'USD' , 1

INSERT INTO #Currency
SELECT 'USD' ,243   UNION ALL
SELECT 'USD',212    UNION ALL
SELECT 'USD', 432   UNION ALL
SELECT 'EUR',578    UNION ALL
SELECT 'EUR',112    UNION ALL
SELECT 'EUR', 578   UNION ALL
SELECT 'GBP', 965   UNION ALL
SELECT 'GBP',309

SELECT * FROM #Exchange_Rate

SELECT a.Currency,AMOUNT,a.AMOUNT * b.FX [Amount IN USD] 
FROM #Currency a INNER JOIN #Exchange_Rate b ON a.Currency=b.Currency
```

[image: Desired Output]